# how to use php in gwt

Tags: java, php, eclipse, gwt

it's as it says on the title

First of all, I would like to apologize if this is a dumb question =[

so basically i'm trying to send email through gwt. I have no idea how gwt mail work so instead I tried to use php way (which is more familiar to me) but I have no idea how to get this working.

So.. in my war folder I have my index.html and email.php that I've created. In my index.html, I have a form that calls my email.php.

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "did you make sure to fill everything?";
    return false;
   }


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the ''           replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\n Message:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@somedomain.com\n"; // This is the email     address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

above is my php code that I am currently using. However not only eclipse does not recognize php but also when I press my button, it only prints out this code and not running it.

Does this happen to anyone and can anyone please help me?

Thank you =]

Comment: php is a server based web technology. The code is executed on the server and the output is sent to the client for further interpretation. GWT is a client and server technology, providing a javascript client with an interface to services running on the server. While it is feasible to use GWT with a php backend, I am not sure, if you are asking for that here. Sending an email in GWT would usually be implemented by an email service on the server that is used by the client code. The client code will collect all the data using form fields and javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do:

- Recreate the email form in GWT with FormPanel, or
- create your own POST-Request in GWT with RequestBuilder

In both cases: the 'echo' statements that your PHP form returns will **not** be appended to the HTML page but returned to you as a String. You will have to decide what to do (tell the user? take other action) in your GWT code.

Recreate as form panel:

```
// create the textboxes of the form with their proper form names
TextBox tbName = new TextBox();
tbName.setName( "name" );
TextBox tbEmail = new TextBox();
tbEmail.setName( "email" );
TextBox tbMessage = new TextBox();
tbMessage.setName( "message" );

// create the form panel
final FormPanel emailFormPanel = new FormPanel();
// TODO: add the form panel to some kind of parent widget / ui object
emailFormPanel.setAction( "/contextRoot/path/to/email.php" );
emailFormPanel.setMethod( "POST" );

// add the textboxes to the form panel
emailFormPanel.add( tbName );
emailFormPanel.add( tbEmail );
emailFormPanel.add( tbMessage );

// create the form submit button
Button btnSubmit = new Button( "Submit", new ClickHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    emailFormPanel.submit();
  }

} );

// create the formpanel handler for a successful submit
// any error message ("did you forget to ...") will be returned here
emailFormPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler( new SubmitCompleteHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {

    String errorString = event.getResults();
    // TODO: decide what to do with a potential non-empty string
  }
} );
```

Create your own POST-Request with RequestBuilder:

```
// create the textboxes of the form with their proper form names
final TextBox tbName = new TextBox();
final TextBox tbEmail = new TextBox();
final TextBox tbMessage = new TextBox();

// create the form submit button
Button btnSubmit = new Button( "Submit", new ClickHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    submitEmailFormRequestBuilder( tbName, tbEmail, tbMessage );

  }

} );
// TODO: add textboxes and Submit-Button to the DOM-tree
```

submit the textbox values:

```
protected void submitEmailFormRequestBuilder(TextBox name, TextBox email, TextBox message) {

  // create the request content in a way that the php script can read it:
  // for every textbox the php textbox-name = user-value
  StringBuilder requestData = new StringBuilder();
  requestData.append( "name=" + name.getValue() );
  requestData.append( "&email=" + email.getValue() );
  requestData.append( "&message=" + message.getValue() );

  // create the REST request callback
  RequestCallback callback = new RequestCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
      String errorMessage = response.getText();

      // TODO: handle potential error-message

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
      // TODO: handle timeouts and other sending failures like cross-domain posting

    }
  };

  // create the REST request as POST request
  RequestBuilder build = new RequestBuilder( RequestBuilder.POST, "/contextRoot/email.php" );
  try {
    build.sendRequest( requestData.toString(), callback );
  }
  catch (RequestException e) {
    // handle exception
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if index.html is not your GWT starting page where the .nocache.js module is called, then you could include it in your GWT code with an IFrame.